# Increase value by 1 on button click

Tags: php

I am trying to make this code increase the value of $clicks by 1 every time I click the button, but I cannot seem to get it working. Any inputs?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="click_button" value="Click..">
</form>
<?php
$clicks = 0;
echo $clicks;

if (isset($_POST['click_button'])) {
    $clicks = $clicks + (1);
}
```

Comment: You're not using POST correctly. You should POST PHP to another page.

Comment: `$clicks` is always `0`. Per your assignment, `$clicks = 0;`. To have it save use sessions, it is suppose to be global to all users?

Comment: @EliSadoff `POST` is being used correctly, just the processing logic is incorrect. This will/would submit to the page it is in.

Comment: Good thinking with the global to all users question. From the looks of it they're just new to PHP and trying to figure out how it all works. @Kaikai55 even if you weren't resetting $clicks at the beginning of the script it wouldn't matter. Every variable in the script get's thrown away as soon as the script is done executing (EXCEPT session variables :) )

Answer (score 3):

It's because as soon as the page get's reloaded, $clicks goes away. You need to store $clicks in the $_SESSION superglobal. Then, the value of $clicks won't go away every time the page is reloaded.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="click_button" value="Click..">
</form>
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['click_button'])) {
    $_SESSION['clicks'] += 1 ;
} else {
    $_SESSION['clicks'] = 0;
}

echo($_SESSION['clicks']);
```

NOTE: don't forget to include `session_start();` at the very beginning of the script. Otherwise, the script won't have access to $_SESSION

Answer (score 0):

Actually, PHP isn’t exactly working like JavaScript. After you press a button, the value is posted to the PHP Web Server, which increments the value. **BUT then**, after that, the `$_POST[];` value remains the same, ***even after you let go*** of the button. So, if you clicked it once, even if you clicked it again, the `$_POST[];` value just remains the same, therefore not making any change to the `clicks;` variable after incrementing it once. The only way is to use JavaScript and find a way to connect it to your code.

P.S. There is nothing wrong with that `form action=“”` part of your code. Everything is right with your HTML. You just need to convert the PHP code to JavaScript.